# android studio: everything correct on an activity but lunching it cause malfunctioning

Tags: android-studio

I'm working on an android application, i added a new activity, that activity launches when i click on some button from my app, the IDE (android studio) isn't showing any errors, except that the name of the java class and the XML file i added is red (more like orange), nothing goes wrong till i click the button that launches the activity I'm talking about, it makes the app shut down.

here's my XML and java class that i added:

**activity_bbel.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas

.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="molfix.dev.molfix.Activities.Menu.BBEstLa.BBELActivity">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:background="#91d0f0"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/toolbar_bb_e_l"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="19dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_back"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/b_back"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_conseils"
    android:id="@+id/b_conseils"
    android:layout_marginTop="125dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_carnet_sante"
    android:id="@+id/b_carnet_sante"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/b_conseils"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

**BBELActivity.java**

```
package molfix.dev.molfix.Activities.Menu.BBEstLa;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import molfix.dev.molfix.Activities.Menu.BBEnRoute.BBERActivity;
import molfix.dev.molfix.R;

/**
 * Created by AminLRoy on 21-Jul-17.
 */

public class BBELActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button b_back;
    String pseudo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bbel);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    pseudo = intent.getExtras().getString("pseudo");

    b_back   =(Button) findViewById(R.id.b_back);

    b_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            BBELActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Any ideas about how to solve this?

Comment: Add the stacktrace to the question.

Comment: what's the stacktrace? @ZeekHuge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, the problem was that the new Activity added wasn't mentioned in the manifest file.